# Ler xml com XStream

Tags: java, xml

Eu tenho um exercício sobre leitura de xml em java. Meu professor indicou usar a biblioteca XStream e não estou conseguindo. Li sobre a documentação, mas não conseguir identificar o problema. 
 Tenho a classe Transacao com todas as variáveis e seus gets e sets. Uso a mesma classe para fazer com um json usando o Gson e funciona normalmente.
o Main:

```
{

import java.io.File;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;


    public static void main(String[] args){


        File remessajson = new File("C:remessa.xml");
        System.out.println(remessajson.exists());
        XStream xs = new XStream();

        String xml = xs.toXML(remessajson);     
        Transacao a = (Transacao)xs.fromXML(xml);


        System.out.println(a.getBancoPag());


    }
```

Esta apresentando o erro:

> ```
> Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable.
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to pack.Transacao
>   at pack.Main.main(Main.java:19)
> true
> ```

Os primeiros itens do xml:

```
<list>
<br.com.pageseguro.RemessaCartaoCredito>
<nome>Adelaide Carvalhaes</nome>
<CPF>56608514522</CPF>
<bancoRecebimento>Caixa Econômica</bancoRecebimento>
<bancoPagamento>Banco Safra</bancoPagamento>
<data>2018-09-02 02:58:10.96 UTC</data>
<valor>362.4101749037519</valor>
<numeroCartao>98315792</numeroCartao>
<nomeTitular>LIEDSON LAGO</nomeTitular>
<parcelas>2</parcelas>
</br.com.pageseguro.RemessaCartaoCredito>
<br.com.pageseguro.RemessaCartaoCredito>
<nome>Viriato Ayres</nome>
<CPF>41057727598</CPF>
<bancoRecebimento>Banco do Brasil</bancoRecebimento>
<bancoPagamento>Banco do Brasil</bancoPagamento>
<data>2018-09-02 02:58:10.96 UTC</data>
<valor>475.60665046855246</valor>
<numeroCartao>92579840</numeroCartao>
<nomeTitular>VIRIATO AYRES</nomeTitular>
<parcelas>6</parcelas>
</br.com.pageseguro.RemessaCartaoCredito>......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **FileReader** para ler seu arquivo e passa como parâmetro no método `fromXML(fileReader)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("C:\\remessa.xml"));
    System.out.println(remessajson.exists());
    XStream xs = new XStream();

    Transacao a = (Transacao)xs.fromXML(reader);


    System.out.println(a.getBancoPag());


}
```

Comment: Cara, desculpe a demora. Mas funcionou dessa forma mesmo. Eu tinha feito de uma outra, mas com sua sugestão ficou mais fácil. Obrigado mano.